# ng2-file-upload 500 internal server issue

Tags: node.js, api, angular

I have installed this ng2-file-upload package but i am having some problems while upload a image its showing me the following error in console

OPTIONS http://localhost:3000/api/ 500 (Internal Server Error)

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.

my api server.js file code is

```
var express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var fs = require('fs');
var app = express();

var DIR = './uploads/';

var upload = multer({dest: DIR});

app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 
    "POST, PUT, OPTIONS,   DELETE, GET");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200');

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, 
    PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type');
    next();
});


 app.get('/api', function (req, res) {
  res.end('file catcher example');
 });

app.post('/api', function (req, res) {
 upload(req, res, function (err) {
    if (err) {
      return res.end(err.toString());
    }
    res.end('File is uploaded');
   });
});

var PORT = process.env.PORT || 3000;

app.listen(PORT, function () {
 console.log('Working on port ' + PORT);
});
```

AdminComponent.ts code

```
 import { FileSelectDirective, FileDropDirective, FileUploader, 
 Headers  } from 'ng2-file-upload/ng2-file-upload';

 const URL = 'http://localhost:3000/api/';

@Component({
  selector  : 'app-admin',
  templateUrl   : './admin.component.html',
  styleUrls : ['./admin.component.css']
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace this:

```
app.use(function (req, res, next) {
 res.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", 
    "POST, PUT, OPTIONS,   DELETE, GET");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://localhost:4200');

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PATCH, 
    PUT, DELETE, OPTIONS');

    header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Origin, Content-Type');
    next();
});
```

with

```
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://localhost:4200');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", true);
    res.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", 'Origin,X-Requested-With,Content-Type,Accept,content-type,application/json');
    next();
  });
```

Comment: i have updated the code that you have suggested but now i am having the following error in console

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:3000/api/. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: The value of the 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header in the response must not be the wildcard '*' when the request's credentials mode is 'include'. Origin 'http://localhost:4200' is therefore not allowed access. The credentials mode of requests initiated by the XMLHttpRequest is controlled by the withCredentials attribute.

Comment: Edit the following line

`res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", '*');`

to

`res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", 'http://localhost:4200');`